# Php rand and repeat numbers

Tags: php, random

I create this php script for generate random numbers but my problem , these numbers repit in many cases and no get different number whitout repit

```
> <?php
> 
> $products=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
> 
> for ($i=0;$i<count($products);$i++) {
> 
> $numbers_[$i]=rand(0,count($products));
> 
> if ($numbers_[$i]=="") { $numbers_[$i]="1"; } else { if
> ($numbers_[$i]>count($products)) { $numbers_[$i]=="10"; } else {
> 
> if ($numbers_[$i]==$numbers_[$i]) { $numbers_[$i]=="*"; }
> 
> 
> }
> 
> 
> }
> 
> 
> print "".$products[$numbers_[$i]]."<br>";
> 
> } ?>
```

Always i need get 5 different numbers .....

This my one problem

Thank´s Regards

Comment: Random numbers are supposed to be random so any number can therefore repeat or not show up at all for a while. If this is an issue, you should explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: With just 10 numbers, you're going to get repeats...

Answer (score 2):

If you are after different numbers, just keep generating random numbers until you get 5 different ones.

For each random number you generate, check your array to see if you already have it. If so, don't add it to the array again and keep generating.

The PHP `in_array()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) makes it easy to check if a value is in your array already.

Answer (score 2):

You query X random numbers with X possible values. They ought to collide.

The code is hard to understand, but I think the condition `if ($numbers_[$i]==$numbers_[$i])` is always true. You say you need "5" different numbers but that "5" is nowhere in the code, so I might still be missing a piece...

If you're trying to randomize the order of elements in $products, try [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

To get the numbers between N and M (N<=M) randomized use `$data=array(); for($i=N;$i<=M;++$i) $data[]=$i; $result=shuffle($data);`

Answer (score 2):

You need "[array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)".

```
$products = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
$rand_keys = array_rand($products, 5); // Get 5 Only
```

You can then loop through the returned Keys and print out the Product numbers or any other details.

```
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    echo $products[$key];
}
```

Comment: No probs. I've just fixed a small bug in my code. It should be ok now.

Comment: How did you go? Did you find a solution? Remember to mark the answer that helped you the most as accepted.